# Rio fieldbinding: LINQ interface not supporterd error on Datetime in LINQ comparison?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have a problem with RIO binding in mvvmcross for the Android targets.

I have a fairly simple model:

```
public class RJParagraph : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public INC<String> Title = new NC<string>();

        //public INC<DateTime> LastSeen = new NC<DateTime>();
        private DateTime _lastSeen;

        public DateTime LastSeen
        {
            get { return _lastSeen; }
            set
            {
                _lastSeen = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => LastSeen);
            }
        }

// constructor etc 
}
```

And I have a Service in the Core project which contains the following LINQ query, where refdate is DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30):

```
mylist.Where(f => f.LastSeen > refdate).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastSeen)
```

When I use the commented line (RIO Datetime field), Nunit tests will run fine, but my Android app will trigger an Interface not supported (comparison) when doing this query. NUnit test does run fine. (note: LastSeen.Value is used in the LINQ query when using Rio)

When I use the non-RIO-version like stated above, it all works fine as intended.

I have been searching for a clue how to get around this... Maybe someone else can give me some pointers? Thanks in advance.

(BTW, my compliments for the effort into this framework)

UPDATE: the full error:

```
System.ArgumentException: does not implement right interface
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: does not implement right interface
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1/DefaultComparer<Cirrious.MvvmCross.FieldBinding.INC`1<System.DateTime>>.Compare (Cirrious.MvvmCross.FieldBinding.INC`1<System.DateTime>,Cirrious.MvvmCross.FieldBinding.INC`1<System.DateTime>) <0x004e8>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.SortSequenceContext`2<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph, Cirrious.MvvmCross.FieldBinding.INC`1<System.DateTime>>.Compare (int,int) <0x000e3>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.QuickSort`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.CompareItems (int,int) <0x00067>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.QuickSort`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.MedianOfThree (int,int) <0x000df>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.QuickSort`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.Sort (int,int) <0x000f7>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.QuickSort`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.PerformSort () <0x000f7>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.QuickSort`1/<Sort>c__Iterator39<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.MoveNext () <0x0019f>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateTakeIterator>c__Iterator30`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.MoveNext () <0x004cf>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Collections.Generic.List`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>.AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>) <0x0016b>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at System.Collections.Generic.List`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Models.RJParagraph>) <0x001bb>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Services.MockTocService.History () <IL 0x000a7, 0x004af>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.ViewModels.IndexHistoryViewModel..ctor (JaarverslaggevingApp.Core.Services.IGetTocService) <IL 0x00016, 0x00113>
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at JaarverslaggevingApp.UI.Android.Fragments.IndexHistoryFragment.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Android.OS.Bundle) [0x0000b] in f:\JaarverslaggevingApp\JaarverslaggevingApp\JR_Android\Views\Fragments\IndexHistoryFragment.cs:25
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00021] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/0cc7ae3b/source/monodroid-bindings/Compatibility-v4/bindings/obj/platform-15/src/generated/Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.cs:953
07-18 11:31:29.730 I/MonoDroid(20500): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.bd483370-f096-4010-b752-21dc83bc68f2 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0x00063>
Unhandled Exception:
```

Comment: Can you post the exception detail on the interface not supported - also can you say where are you testing the Android - on an emulator or on a device? in debug or release?

Comment: Exception details, see updated question.

Comment: The exception clearly shows the compiler trying to apply `Compare<int, int>` to the objects of type `INC~1<System.DateTime>>`. This is obviously coming out of the `OrderByDescending` clause (which I'm assuming uses `.Value` in your modified code. As in my answer, I'd recommend trying to work around this by giving the Mono compiler some hints about what types are involved (or by passing in a comparer to use?) and I'd recommend reproducing this in a simple test case and sending it to the compiler teams as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the issue of human error, and wasting hours of puzzling :( I had removed all RIO code because of another problem (that in the end was no RIO problem at all). So at first I had added the .Value everywhere, but after restore the RIO code I had only added the .Value where the compiler reported codes in errors. The Date comparison to refdate was reported, but not the .OrderByDescending, because at compiler time it is no problem to compare a INC to a INC...

Looking in my repository I can only blame myself :)

Thanks Stuart for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can think that might be causing this are:

1. If this is some kind of linker bug where Xamarin.Android is removing the comparable support for `DateTime` before deploying to the Android test device
2. If this is some kind of compiler difference where Xamarin.Android is somehow picking up the base `INotifyChange` interface for `Value` which uses `object` instead of the `INotifyChange<T>` interface which uses `new` to override `Value` to type `T`.

---

To test if it's the first, can you deploy in debug with the linker set to 'none' - does the problem still occur?

If it's the first, then you can trick the linker into including this interface using a file like `LinkerPleaseInclude`.

---

To test if it's the second, can you change your code to:

```
   mylist.Where(f => ((DateTime)f.LastSeen.Value) > refdate)
         .OrderByDescending(f => ((DateTime)f.LastSeen.Value))
```

Does this run OK?

If it's the second, then I think this may need reporting back to Xamarin and/or Microsoft for them to investigate the difference in compiler behaviour.

---

If it's neither of these, perhaps you might be able to share a more full sample somewhere which demonstrates the problem.